# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. (mscorlib) When clicking Contents Button to view backup device

Tags: sql-server

I want to restore a full backup of a SQL Express 2017 database to SQL Server Standard 2019
Both are on Oracle Linux 8.5

[image: Select backup device]

When I click the contents button I get the following error

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. (mscorlib)
------------------------------
Program Location:
  at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
  at System.Convert.ToBoolean(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.BakDevMediaContents.InitBackupSets(Restore sqlRestore)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.BakDevMediaContents.InitProp()
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.BakDevMediaContents.InitializeOffline(CDataContainer dataContainer)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.BackupDeviceContents..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer, IHelpProvider f1help)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreSelectBackupSource.buttonContents_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks.RestoreDatabaseGeneralView.buttonSelectDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ActionHandlers.DialogBasedActionHandler.RunTaskFormThread(Object contextObject)
```

Comment: looking at https://www.kodyaz.com/articles/specified-cast-is-not-valid-sqlmanagerui.aspx

Comment: and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8e462ef-9d09-4b7c-887a-ab3afed0ed84/problem-in-restoring-backup-file?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that mssql tools, which controls the backup, was at two different versions.

We had to upgrade
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15